# Execution Timed Out (12000 ms) : How can I pass this error

Tags: javascript

When i am trying to solve problem on codewars , get this error.

My code passes all the tests but not optimized . Do u have any advice ?

Problem : https://www.codewars.com/kata/551dd1f424b7a4cdae0001f0

Javascript :

```
function whoIsNext(names, r){
  let drinker;
  for(let a = 1 ; a <= r; a++){
    drinker = names[0]
    names.shift()
    names.push(drinker, drinker)
  }
  return drinker
}
```

Comment: you can combine the first 2 lines from your loop `drinker = names.shift();` but the effect will be marginal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and works but it takes too much time for all the array-operations espacially when r is getting great. So there is another approach necessary:
Look if with the count of drinkers r can be satisfied if not so decrease r about the number of these drinkers and double the drinkers. Go this on till drinkers satisfy r.
Now you have only to divide r through the number each original drinker was multiplied and you get the drinker.

```js
function whoIsNext(names, r){
  let drinker;
  let multi = 1;
  let length = names.length;
  while (r>multi*length) {
    r -= multi*length;
    multi *= 2;
  }
  return names[parseInt((r-1)/multi)];
}

let names = [ "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard"];
console.log(whoIsNext(names, 1)); // == "Sheldon"
console.log(whoIsNext(names, 52));// == "Penny"
console.log(whoIsNext(names, 7230702951)); // == "Leonard"
// for (i=1; i<=100; i++) {console.log(i, whoIsNext(names, i))}
```

Comment: This solution is very fast but gets fails on some tests(1111 passes ,5 fail ,i get)

Comment: Can you give me some of the fails with the correct solution than I can take a look on it.

Comment: I found the error, it was in the return I used r/multi but I need `(r-1)/multi`. By the way:  The differentiation(multi==1) is not necessary, so it's minimal shorter. If you remove the comment out in the last line you get all results.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but as it takes a moment in the last input, due to execution time it gets an 'error'. The code should be improved.

This is my suggestion (Instead of pushing values in a large array, everything is stored in an array of arrays), see this quickly example:

```js
const whoIsNext = (names, r) => {
  names = names.map(n => [n,1]);
  let qi = 0, j = 0;
  while (j < r) {
    j += names[qi][1]*=2;
    qi = (qi+1) % names.length;
  }
  return names[(names.length+qi-1)%names.length][0];
}

//The last test case in codewars
const result = whoIsNext(["Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard"], 7230702951);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This solution is very fast too, but gets fails on some tests (1078 passes ,38 fail ). I like your idea thats really fast

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
function whoIsNext(names, r) {
    let foundedInArray = names.length

    while (r > foundedInArray) {
        r -= foundedInArray
        foundedInArray *= 2
    }

    return (names[Math.ceil(r/(foundedInArray/names.length) - 1)])
}
```

As you can see on array: **['A', 'B', 'C']**, there will be this "string": **"ABC|AABBCC|AAAABBBBCCCC|..."**.

The point is that you always add twice the elements of the "previous field" (separated by a vertical bar). As you can see, I at first control, if length of "extended queue is greater or same as value **r**", then in while cykle I reduce this value, because I am looking only in "currently enlarged part of array". Then I simply return the value so that I know that the magnified part of the field is n times the length of the original field. So I de facto divide the number and round it down to get the desired index of the original field.

Sorry for my grammar and also possible complicated explanation of the code.

- List item

Comment: BTW: I had first no idea, how to pass throught the "timed out" so i also looking for answer. So this is sligthly inspired by others. ;)